# select count, sum using PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, select, count, pdo

How can I get count(*) or SUM(col1) using PHP PDO

I have used

```
$STH_SELECT = $dbh->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM Table");
$STH_SELECT->execute;
$result = $STH_SELECT->fetchAll;
$Count = $result[0][0];
```

Is this correct and Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to use prepared statement when you aren't entering any data into the query.

```
$STH_SELECT = $dbh->query("SELECT count(*) FROM Table");
$Count = $STH_SELECT->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: And offers noticeable performance increase over prepared statements.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $STH_SELECT->fetchColumn();// first row, first col
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

Answer (score 0):

I am using

```
$Count = $dbh->query("SELECT count(*) FROM Table")->fetchColumn();
```

Kind of shorter ?